# Access table from another database in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which has some code as shown below.

```
select count(*) as Count, datepart(yyyy, [LogDate]) as [Year]
from  ViewAssociate..Auth_Log 
where ActionCode = 1
group by datepart(yyyy, [LogDate])
order by [Year]
```

Now ViewAssociate is a different database. The issue is that the user that has access to the Stored Proc does not have access to the other database and so I am getting an error

```
The server principal "View" is not able to access the database "viewassociate" under the current security context.
```

So I am just wondering how can I access the other database table from this one. I can pass the credentials for the viewassociate database but not sure how to change my query to fetch data using the credentials. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is [not that easy to do correctly](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) (particularly [this section](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#crossdb)). It's fairly easy to do incorrectly by throwing around global permissions.

Comment: Ok Thanks..Not sure if this was a bad question that I got a closed vote.

Comment: Look into EXECUTE AS...